# Spring Boot GraphQL Server with embedded Keycloak instance wont start

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, graphql-java

what I am actually trying is, to built an backend with Spring Boot, this backend is split into two modules. One auth-server (embedded keycloak-server) and one resource-server (graphql-server).

In there I've a so service, called KeycloakService. This service has many public methods to communicate with the embedded keycloak instance. Every method has a meaningful equivalent in the graphql schema to create the possibility, to e.g. create new users or roles over a graphql mutation.

The auth-server runs without any problems.

But when I start up the resource server it crashes with the following stacktrace:

It tells me that he couldnt find TestLdapConnectionRepresentation.class, but I dont understand why he is trying to search for it, because I never used this feature of Keycloak.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keycloakService' defined in file [C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\software\backend\resource-server\target\classes\com\software\backend\resource\services\KeycloakService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.software.backend.resource.services.KeycloakService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/representations/idm/TestLdapConnectionRepresentation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 159 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.software.backend.resource.services.KeycloakService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/representations/idm/TestLdapConnectionRepresentation
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1312) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 171 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/representations/idm/TestLdapConnectionRepresentation
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3244) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:3269) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1918) ~[na:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ProxyBuilder.proxy(ProxyBuilder.java:57) ~[resteasy-client-3.9.1.Final.jar:3.9.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.SubResourceInvoker.invoke(SubResourceInvoker.java:67) ~[resteasy-client-3.9.1.Final.jar:3.9.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76) ~[resteasy-client-3.9.1.Final.jar:3.9.1.Final]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.realm(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.realm(Keycloak.java:114) ~[keycloak-admin-client-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
    at com.software.backend.resource.services.KeycloakService.<init>(KeycloakService.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 173 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.keycloak.representations.idm.TestLdapConnectionRepresentation
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 189 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

This not the complete stacktrace, but because of StackOverflows char limitation, I only publish the line which I think what are important. If you need some more information, to be able to help me. Let me know.

Hopefully there is someone out there, who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and it seems Gradle does not resolve the "keycloak-core" dependency correctly (resolves version 8.0.1):

```sh
$ gradlew -q dependencies

...
\--- org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:11.0.2
 +--- org.keycloak:keycloak-core:11.0.2 -> 8.0.1
...
```

I also added the "keycloak-core" dependency directly into my project which solved the problem:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-core:11.0.2'
   implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:11.0.2'
}
```

```sh
$ ./gradlew -q dependencies

...
\--- org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:11.0.2
 +--- org.keycloak:keycloak-core:11.0.2
...
```